# Python: Calculate mathematical values in new row in dataframe based on few specific previous rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, math

I have the below pandas dataframe:

Input:

```
        A              B        C
        Expense        2        3
        Sales          5        6
        Travel         8        9
```

My Expected Output is:

```
        A              B        C
        Expense        2        3
        Sales          5        6
        Travel         8        9
        Total Exp      10       12
```

The last tow is basically total of `row 1` and `row 3`. This is a very simplified example, i actually have to perform complex calculation on a huge dataframe.

Is there a way in python to perform such calculation?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select rows by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and `sum`, then assign to new row:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = df.iloc[0] + df.iloc[2]
```

Or:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = df.iloc[[0,2]].sum()
```

---

```
print (df)
   A   B   C
0  1   2   3
1  4   5   6
2  7   8   9
3  8  10  12
```

EDIT: First idea is create index by `A` column, so you can use `loc` with new value of `A`, but last step is convert index to column by `reset_index`:

```
df = df.set_index('A')
df.loc['Total Exp'] = df.iloc[[0,2]].sum()
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
           A   B   C
0    Expense   2   3
1      Sales   5   6
2     Travel   8   9
3  Total Exp  10  12
```

Similar is possible selecting by `loc` by labels - here `Expense` and `Travel`:

```
df = df.set_index('A')
df.loc['Total Exp'] = df.loc[['Expense', 'Travel']].sum()
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
           A   B   C
0    Expense   2   3
1      Sales   5   6
2     Travel   8   9
3  Total Exp  10  12
```

Or is possible filter out first column with `1:` and add value back by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = df.iloc[[0,2], 1:].sum().reindex(df.columns, fill_value='Total Exp')
print (df)
          A   B   C
0    Expense   2   3
1      Sales   5   6
2     Travel   8   9
3  Total Exp  10  12
```

Or you can set value of `A` separately:

```
s = df.iloc[[0,2]].sum()
s.loc['A'] = 'Total Exp'
df.loc[len(df.index)] = s
print (df)
           A   B   C
0    Expense   2   3
1      Sales   5   6
2     Travel   8   9
3  Total Exp  10  12
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks. This also adds up the text in the rows, is there a way to rename it in final output?
for ex: row1 is `Management Net Income` and row 3 is `Free Cash Flow` then new row created is getting the rowname as `Management Net IncomeFree Cash Flow`

Comment: Do you think instead `3` need `some text` ? like `df.loc['some text'] = df.iloc[0] + df.iloc[2]` ?

Comment: No, here 3 is a index. In my case, its like col1 is rownames. and actual values start from column two. Modified my original dataframe in the question.

Comment: i couldn't have asked for a better descriptive answer. thanks